# How to access method of Project A into Project B in nodejs, i am using nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

i have MailEvent class and want to use SendEmail method in client project. i use NPM link to share code for client project. but i can't access this method. how can i access this method in client project. i am using nestJS framework. thanks

```
@Injectable()
export class MailEvent {
  constructor(private eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) {}

  // store email details to RabbitMQ
  SendEmail() {
    amqplib.connect(
      'amqp://localhost',
      (connectionError, connection) => {
        if (connectionError) {
          throw connectionError;
        }
        connection.createChannel((channelError, channel) => {
          if (channelError) {
            throw channelError;
          }
          const queue = 'Test_emails_queue';
          channel.assertQueue(queue, { durable: false });
          channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(email)));
          // create event for sending email
          this.eventEmitter.emit('send_email', email);
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In nestjs we can create a reusable module. Then, this module can be imported to another module. If the module is stored in separated repo, then we can build the module first before installing it to another repo using NPM.

Steps to do:

1. generate nestjs resource, e.g. MailEventModule on the terminal. It will also create the controller and service class

```js
nest g resource mail-event
```

2. export the service via the module file `mail-event.module.ts`

   ```js
   import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
   import { MailEventService } from './mail-event.service';

   @Module({
     providers: [MailEventService],
     exports: [MailEventService]
   })
   export class MailEventModule { }
   ```
3. Build the module. It will create a new folder named `DIST` containing the module ready to be installed in another repo/project

```js
npm run build
```

4. upload the mail-event module to npm
5. install mail-event in the client project using npm command, e.g. `npm install mail-event`
6. Import the module to the client project in `client-project.module.ts`

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailEventModule } from 'mail-event';

@Module({
  imports: [MailEventModule]
})
export class ClientProjectModule { }
```

7. Add MailEventService as dependency to the client project service in `client-project.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailEventService } from 'mail-event';

@Injectable()
export class ClientProjectService {

    constructor(private mailEventService: MailEventService) { }
    
    myFunction() {
      this.mailEventService.sendEmail();
    }
}
```

If you have tried this steps, please give us the feedback whether it works or not. Thank you